# Subquery as an offset Argument- Alternative of LAG() Function in DB2

Tags: database, db2, sql-function

I would like to ask you a question. Generally, we know that LAG() function can be expressed us ***LAG(column expression, Offset, [defaul value]) OVER (ORDER BY ...)***. The offset can't be a subquery in DB2. Does anyone know **a function in db2** that has the same functionality with LAG() and it can take as ***an offset argument a subquery or a calculated field*** that is calculated in the previous step in a subquery from the source?

So the case is as follows, I want to use lag function but the offset argument LAG(column expression, offset,[default value]) OVER(ORDER BY . . .)
is not a constant value.

For example I have:

**LAG(CAST(DATE_utc AS VARCHAR),
offset,
0)
OVER (PARTITION BY ID,
ID_2 ORDER BY DATE_utc) AS PREV
FROM

(
SELECT *, CAST(count(fid)
OVER (PARTITION BY f|| t, ID,
ID_2) AS INTEGER) AS offset
FROM SCHEMA.TABLE_1
WHERE ID = 65020475
)
AS inner_dataset***

As you can see the [offset] is calculated from the TABLE_1 and is used as a parameter on the LAG function on the outer level.
However, this results in the following error:
SQL Error [42815]: ***The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter
in position "2" of routine "LAG" is incorrect.*** Is there any alternative to this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: As per my comment on your previous question, please include examples to demonstrate your needs : [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Comment: Ok, I added an example in my main post.

Comment: Please read the link. You need to include example data.

Comment: Here's a fiddle that demonstrates the issue: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=d09b592ab39e7cb4fcb7b73e591a1bd8 with the error `SQL0171N  The statement was not processed because the data type, length or value of the argument for the parameter in position "2" of routine "LAG" is incorrect. Parameter name: "".  SQLSTATE=42815 SQLCODE=-171`.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I mean! Hope that this will help .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `row_number()` and a self join as in:

```
with tt (a, rn) as (
    select a, row_number() over (order by a) as rn from t
) 
select t1.a, t2.a as lag_a, t1.rn, t2.rn 
from tt t1
left join tt t2
   on t2.rn = t1.rn - (select max(x) from p);
```

[Modified Impalers Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=72005132c896069fb24a22efd6680379)